# Vertically connected boxes with text and math inside them

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to have lots of boxes (see http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/) with text and math inside them. These boxes are arranged vertically and connected by a line.

How may I do it with LaTeX?

Comment: Do you want to do this using TikZ or the `xy-pic` package? You added the tag for both but your question links a TikZ example. IMHO there is no reason to use `xy-pic`.

Comment: A sketch of the desired result would be very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here a solution based on the [TeXample you linked](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/boxes-with-text-and-math/). It uses the `positioning library to position the boxes below each other.

You need to give every box its own name (like `box1`, `box2`, ..., or any other label) so that you can reference them in the picture. Then use the drawing commands to connect them like `\draw [your style] (box1) -- (box2);`

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

% Define box and box title style
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=red, text=white]


\begin{tikzpicture}

% First box
\node [mybox] (box1){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
        To calculate the horizontal position the kinematic differential
        equations are needed:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u\cos\psi -v\sin\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\sin\psi + v\cos\psi
        \end{align}
        For small angles the following approximation can be used:
        \begin{align}
            \dot{n} &= u -v\delta_\psi \\
            \dot{e} &= u\delta_\psi + v
        \end{align}
    \end{minipage}
};
% Fancy title of first box (remove if not required)
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box1.north west) {A fancy title};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box1.east) {$\clubsuit$};
%
% Second Box, placed with 1cm distance below box1
\node [mybox,below=1cm of box1.south] (box2) {%
    \begin{minipage}[t!]{0.5\textwidth}
        Fermat's Last Theorem states that
        \[
            x^n + y^n = z^n
        \]
        has no non-zero integer solutions for $x$, $y$ and $z$ when $n > 2$.
    \end{minipage}
    };
% Draw a connection line between box1 and box2 with the same style like the box:
\draw [mybox] (box1) -- (box2);
% Now draw the fancy title (so that it is on top of the connection box)
\node[fancytitle] at (box2.north) {Fermat's Last Theorem};

% Third Box, placed with 1cm distance below box2
\node [mybox,below=1cm of box2.south] (box3) {%
    \begin{minipage}[t!]{0.5\textwidth}
        Fermat's Last Theorem states that
        \[
            x^n + y^n = z^n
        \]
        has no non-zero integer solutions for $x$, $y$ and $z$ when $n > 2$.
    \end{minipage}
    };
% Draw a connection line between box2 and box3 with the same style like the box:
\draw [mybox] (box2) -- (box3);
% Now draw the fancy title (so that it is on top of the connection box)
\node[fancytitle] at (box3.north) {Fermat's Last Theorem};

\end{tikzpicture}
%

\end{document}
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

What you are asking for seems very simple to achieve using `TikZ`. A MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{box} = [rectangle, draw, black]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (first) [box] {some text, and some maths: $a = 1$};
\node (second) [box,below of=first] {other text, and some more maths: $b = 2$};
\node (third) [box,below of=second] {$c = 3$};
\draw (first) -- (second) -- (third);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here is the resulting picture:

[image: Vertically connected boxes]

Comment: Thank you. Right now, I do not have 15 reputation points to vote-up this useful answer.